# Getting the “RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded” error

Tags: javascript, loops, callback

how can i add function on top of the already existing function?

i'm using following way and it gives me error on `resources.onload`

```
    resource = document.getElementById(this.id);

    if (resource && resource.getAttribute('data-loading'))
    {           
        onloadOthers = resource.onload;
        onloadThis   = this.onComplete.bind(this);

//following line give error

        resource.onload = function () { // callback loops again and again!!!!!!
            if (typeof onloadOthers == "function")
                onloadOthers();
            onloadThis();
        };

        return; // just added another callback, no need to add it again.
    }
    else if (resource)
    {           
        this.onComplete();
        return; // already exist
    }

    if (this.type == "js")
    { //if filename is a external JavaScript file
        var code = document.createElement('script');
        code.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
        code.setAttribute('data-loading', 'yes');
        code.setAttribute("src", this.file);
        code.onload = this.onComplete.bind(this);
        code.onreadystatechange = code.onload; // ie fix
    }
```

Comment: The error usually means a never ending loop

Comment: yes i know that. how can i fix it? i want to add previous callback on top of new callback. so they both get triggered onload.

Comment: `onloadOthers` may cause infinite recursion. Make sure that the `unloadOthers` variable is contained in a new closure.

Comment: @RobW i agree.. anyway to solve it?

Comment: @Basit Yes, put [`var`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) before `onloadOthers` (assuming that the code you've shown is contained in `function(){` and `}`, which created a closure. Currently, your code probably "recycles" the `resource` and `onloadOthers` (global) variables. By prefixing `var`, the variables will stay in the local scope.

Comment: @RobW can you write that in answer, so i can accept it. it works :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the `onloadOthers` and `resources` variables in a new closure, by prefixing the [`var`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) keyword.

Currently, your code "recycles" these (global) variables, because they're declared in a non-local scope:

```
var onloadOthers;
function func() {
    onloadOthers = ...;
    resource.onload = function() {
        onloadOthers(); // Calls the global `onloadOthers` function.
    };
}
func(); // Defines `onloadOthers`
func(); // Overwrites `onloadOthers`
```

By moving the variable to a local scope, all instances of the function will have an "own" `onloadOthers` variable, which solves the problem.

If you want to learn more about this topic, read [How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work).