# Javascript function variable scope

Tags: javascript, variables, scope

What difference does it make to do the following:

```
function (callback) {
    var callback  = callback || false;
    combineCallback = function () {
        callback.apply(window);
        ....
    }
    getJSON(combineCallback);
}
```

Or with this:

```
function (callback) {
    var combineCallback = function () {
        callback.apply(window);
        ....
    }
    getJSON(combineCallback);
}
```

Does it make any difference to write write `var callback = callback || false;`?

Comment: if the function is called more than once.. will it be overright with previous callback if i don't define var?

Comment: `false.apply()` and `undefined.apply()` throw a similar error, so in that regard there is no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var` will *not* "shadow" a local variable in the same scope. Likewise, `var` will *not* "shadow" a parameter (which is a local variable/binding itself). Simply, each time the function is invoked, `callback` represents a *different local variable* which initially contains the first argument passed; and there is only *one* local variable called `callback`.

Because var doesn't "create" a new variable (search for "hoisting"),

```
function (callback) {
    var callback  = callback || false;
```

and

```
function (callback) {
    callback  = callback || false;
```

are equivalent - no difference. (Although I find the latter *more clear*.)

However, *removing* the `callback = callback || false` *changes the semantics*. In particular, callback may end up with false-y values like 0 without that line. Whether or not this is needed/useful here is a different issue as `(false).apply(..)` will still result in an error.

Here is a simple TTL for `x || y`:

```
x        y    x || y
-------  ---  ------
TRUTH-y  ANY  x
FALSE-y  ANY  y
```

Comment: I think that the OP's question is if including `var callback  = callback || false;` in the code will make a difference or not.

Comment: you edited the answer milliseconds before I posted the comment.Sorry!

Comment: f the function is called more than once.. will it be overright with previous callback if i don't define var? –

Comment: @Juhana i have head problem with var before, thats why i was asking.. this was the error before http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16608355/getting-the-rangeerror-maximum-call-stack-size-exceeded-error

Comment: @Basit The problem with the code in the linked question is it *doesn't* use `var`. It would awful if parameters "leaked" scope or were "promoted" to global variables! That would lead to so many bugs that could not help but be avoided! Anyway, the `var` in this case is completely irrelevant to how the code will run.